# Legal age of adulthood

Tags: united-states

If current law establishes that a fetus is considered life at it's first confirmed heartbeat,  shouldn't life start then? At which point does one's age begin. Example: "a delivered baby" on 5/1/0000 would actually be older based on "first heartbeat" detected and not the delivery date? Is age even a question of law?

Comment: It is incorrect that current law establishes that a fetus is considered alive at its first heartbeat.

Comment: Even assuming that current law establishes that a fetus is considered alive at its first heartbeat, age does not have to be defined to be based on "first heartbeat" date. Indeed, age is based on the "birthday," i.e., the date of birth, not heartbeat.

Comment: Any court would consider a birth certificate issued on   '5/1/0000' to be invalid, since the present calendar system has no year 0 (either 1 AD/CE or - 1 BC/BCE) (not to meantioned the fact that the present calender system was introduced in the year 525 AD/CE).

Answer (score 2):

Age is computed based on date of birth. Age is a question of law, for laws regarding drinking, smoking, sex, voting, contractual responsibility, holding the office of president, and many other things.